# Asynchronous inserts in audit table in spring-hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a DB table with many columns and associated Entities. 
Update is supported on some of the columns. I need to maintain history of the data that's overwritten in update/delete in a separate table. Options that I have considered are below:

**1. Hibernate-envers:** Most easiest to use but issue with this is the insert in audit table are synchronous and also it becomes a part of actual transaction. Which is not a desired solution for my use-case.

**2. Debezium:** While it does make the audit insert asynchronous, but it looks like an overkill for my use-case as it includes installation of a lot of services like Kafka, zookeeper and there seem to be multiple points of failure.

**3. JPA listeners:** I can use these to get the data being updated/deleted and call an async insert in history table. Only issue I see here is I'll have to replicate actual entity classes code in the history entities.

Please suggest a solution I can go ahead with. Thanks.